# HTTP_REFERER check isn't working well

Tags: apache-2.2

I have the following configuration:

```
list.map
#################
http:////www.badserver.com http://www.redirectedserver.com
http:////www.badserver.com/attack.html http://www.redirectedserver.com
#################


RewriteMap phishing txt:/opt/rweb/list.map
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^:/?]+)
RewriteCond ${lc:%1} (.+)
RewriteCond ${phishing:%1|NOT-FOUND} !=NOT-FOUND
RewriteRule ^ http://www.server.com [L]
```

The problem is that the last RewriteCond isn't working well. %1 should be only the Domainname but it could not finded in the list.map.

so if the referer is http://www.badserver.com/badsite.html it should also redirect the request.

May someone can help me with this problem.

If i use 
    RewriteCond ${phishing:%{HTTP_REFERER}|NOT-FOUND} !=NOT-FOUND
instead of 
    RewriteCond ${phishing:%1|NOT-FOUND} !=NOT-FOUND
then it's working.

The REFERER is www.badserver.com/attack.html and is listed in the list.map. I only want to check if the domain name of the referer is listet in the list.map. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you give us more detail about how the RewriteCond isn't doing what you expect?  I'm having some difficulty parsing your sentence "%1 should be only the Domainname but it could not finded in the list.map."

Comment: I want to block or redirect all Domains listet in the list.map. It should not matter whether the Referer http://badsite.com/attacke.html or http://badsite.com/attacke/attacke.html. I only want to check if the domain name badsite.com Consists in the Referer. If the domain name is found in the Referer then redirect should be done.

Comment: Please can help me someone!